# How to rename a file in a Chrome App with the Filesystem API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm using the Chrome Filesystem in my Chrome app and I want to rename a local file.  I know how to write a new file, by doing:

```
chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(print_location, function(entry) {
    entry.getFile('file1.txt', {create:true}, function(entry) {
        entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.write(new Blob(['Lorem'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
        });
    });
});
```

which works, but given a file that already exists, how do I rename it (with overwrite)?  Or alternatively how can I delete files, copy files, or move files?  Is this not possible?

UPDATE:

Based on Daniel Herr's explanation that it's shared with HTML file system api, I produced the below code, which solved my issue.

```
function rename_file(file_location, file_old_name, file_new_name){
    chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(file_location, function(entry) {        
        entry.getFile(file_old_name, {create:false}, function(entry) {
            entry.moveTo(file_location, file_new_name, 
                     function(){console.log("success");}, 
                     function(){
                        console.log("fail"); 
                      });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Entry#moveTo

Comment: Using chrome filesystem api though.  Any way to do it there?

Comment: chrome.fileSystem is integrated with the web filesystem. The entries are the same.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  If you throw it in as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: _Please_ don't edit solutions INTO questions. Instead, post another answer. Self-answers are fine and encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is inside a folder you have been given access to, you can use the entry.moveTo method to rename it.

```
fileentry.getParent(function(parent) {
 fileentry.moveTo(parent, "newname")
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Entry#moveTo

Comment: moveTo() has been deprecated and is no longer recommended according to the Mozilla docs linked

Comment: @JeremyBernier That's pretty much irrelevant because the question concerned the user filesystem api of Chrome Apps, which were a Chrome specific proprietary platform distinct from the open Web, and also because Chrome Apps themselves have been depreciated.